# When a vowel is nasalized does it effect on how open/close + front/back it would be?

Tags: phonology, vowels, frontness-backness, nasals, vowel-height

I'm trying to generalize what environments a certain set of phonemes occur, but I'm not sure if nasalization would affect where the vowel would be on the IPA vowel chart. I think my analysis of the data is affected by nasalized vowels, so I want to make sure I'm classifying them correctly! 
Thanks!

Comment: It depends greatly on (a) whether nasalization is phonemically distinct and (b) how many distinct nasal vowels there are. Almost always there will be fewer nasal vowel phonemes than oral. That means the oral vowels will instantiate more contrasts, while the nasal vowels have more room to vary. In languages like English, however, where nasalization is entirely allomorphic, it doesn't really affect vowel quality unless there's a local merger, like US /ɪ/ merging with /ɛ/ before /n/.

Comment: What form is your data set in? Do you just have transcriptions of words? Do you know if nasalization on vowels is phonemic in this language?